# shortcut for creating an javascript object from an array of objects using lodash

Tags: lodash

I often have an `array of objects` and want to make it into an `object of objects` by keying on a specific `key` of the contained objects.

Currently I'm doing something like:

`_.zipObject(_.pluck(results, '_id'), results);`

However, this is such a common thing I wondered if there's a shortcut to do this using Lodash / underscore.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for  `_.indexBy()` http://lodash.com/docs#indexBy

Example from the docs:

```js
var keys = [
  { 'dir': 'left', 'code': 97 },
  { 'dir': 'right', 'code': 100 }
];

_.indexBy(keys, 'dir');
// → { 'left': { 'dir': 'left', 'code': 97 }, 'right': { 'dir': 'right', 'code': 100 } }
```